# Connection very slow with HttpClient or HttpURLConnection in emulator or smarthphone

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, connection, httpclient

I'm riding a url and sending my server for after submitting via post, read the json . I'm having an error where there is a big delay to make the

```
 //VERY SLOW HERE =( 1 a 5 min

httpURLConnection c = ( HttpURLConnection ) u.openConnection (); 
//or 
response = httpclient.execute(httpget); //get or post
```

and

What can be ? How to solve ?

Below the code snippets that make the operation.

These lines are within the doInBackgrund method asynktask . The emulator is 4.4.2 google apis or > 4.0 (because of the push notification ).

Option 1:

```
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
       //VERY SLOW HERE =( 1 a 5 min open connection
        c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        // c.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        c.setUseCaches(false);
        c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        c.connect();
        int status = c.getResponseCode();

        switch (status) {
        case 200:
        case 201:
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

option 2:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpParams httpParameters = httpclient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
    HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(httpParameters, true);

    HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(url);

    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {

        response =httpclient.execute(httpget); //VERY SLOW HERE =( 1 a 5 min

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String json = toString(instream);
            instream.close();
```

Earlier work normally , it did not take more than 10 seconds in the emulator. Help-me please =(

Comment: I thought you have a cache issue but your code looks like correct. I am using volley library and I have not enough experience for direct http connection. Upvoted.

Comment: I think it's a cache, but how and where to find a solution? Previously worked without problems, in the same environment, various designs. I'm using asynktasks and httpconnections. You can help me find the problem? Firewall is disabled, I suspect that is the android or eclipse or even in some operating system thing. But I have no idea how to find the cause.